# How can I download CoreCrypto.framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, cryptography, aes

I need Core Crypto Framework.

But Core Crypto Framework does not exist... in my MacBook.

How can I get Core Crypto Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS, like recent OSX, provides **CommonCrypto** (not CoreCrypto afaik) and it should already be available if you have any recent SDK installed on your Mac.

See Apple [samples](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html) for how to use the API.

Comment: I Download lastest X-code(and sdk). What does sdk version contain CommonCrypto framework? I did use 4.2 ios sdk.

Comment: After upgrade xcode(included lastest sdk), CommonCrypto.framework does not exist...

Comment: CommonCrypto is not a framework itself. The functions (it's a C based API) are available in libSystem. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html